# Rails - method doesn't exist error when trying to use user hook to find out when user signed in - devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Obviously User.first.current_sign_in_at is what I want to use, but how to add this in a hook?

```
before_save :login_hook, :if => current_sign_in_at_changed?
```

but I get method doesn't exist.

Here it seems to work:

[Execute JS code on user sign up/sign in with Rails + Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779321/execute-js-code-on-user-sign-up-sign-in-with-rails-devise)

I have devise :trackable in the model and t.trackable in my migration. The database value is also updated

Comment: there is a devise's helper `user_signed_in?`

Comment: Where are you adding this hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, forget the hook, just try using

```
if (Time.new - current_user.last_sign_in_at) < 600 # seconds, so 10 minutes
  do stuff
else
  # do other stuff, probably a redirect
  # possibly  sign_out_and_redirect(resource_name)
end
```

You probably want this in your application_controller so as to apply to all.

Comment: I need something to get to know if the user just sign in not if he is sign in

Comment: Updated with different approach.

Comment: Sure, other stuff may include signing out the user 'for them' - try and use the devise stuff where you can, for instance, for timeout there is: `http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Timeoutable`